# How to construct a function that passes a tuple-like argument as its input?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a beginner in Python who seeks to create a function that passes a point of the form `(x, y)` and returns the absolute value of the point and a specific line.  As required, I have to define a function like this

```
def calculate_error(m, b, (x_point, y_point) ):
    error = abs(get_y(m, b, x_point) - y_point)
```

I have a trouble passing the point to the function above so that I cannot manipulate either the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate inside the function.  Am I supposed to treat the point `(x,y)` as a tuple or a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the tuple as a single variable and unpack it inside the function:

```
def calculate_error(m, b, point):
    x_point, y_point = point
    error = abs(get_y(m, b, x_point) - y_point)
```

you can then call it passing a tuple:

```
print(calculate_error(1, 2, (3, 4)))
```

Comment: Problem got solved. Appreciate your advice, @Selcuk!